# Pivoting in simplex method for solving linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-algorithm

A common linear programming problem below

min c'x

s.t. Ax<=b

(A is m*n, m is smaller than n)

---

As I know, the pivoting procedure in simplex method lets extreme point jump to another extreme point until it finds the optimal solution.

Extreme point has at most m(the number of constraints) nonzero variables. Variables in extreme point can be divided into two parts, basic variables(nonzero terms) and nonbasic variables(zero terms).

In normal condition, Pivoting change one nonbasic variable to basic variable while one basic variable become nonbasic variable in each iteration.

My question is can a nonbasic variable which was basic before become basic again? If yes, is there an clear or special example that at least one variable does.

Comment: Not sure this question is a good fit for SO. It certainly is possible, e.g., see [here](https://www.usna.edu/Users/math/wakefiel/_files/documents/sa305/notes/note4-3.pdf) and also search cycling and degenerate steps. Also, if nonbasic variables which were basic were not allowed to become basic again, it would mean that as simplex iterates, we are searching over lower dimensional spaces, which is not the case.

Comment: Thank you. I found that degenerage may occur cycling. So it is possible that nonbasic variables which were basic become basic again.

Comment: This can even happen in a single iteration. The entering variable can say be NB UPPER. Then the same variable can be the limiting variable and become NB LOWER.

Comment: seems to be a question from Bertsimas LP book